# Validation if the value exists else no validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So, this is what i've tried already.

```
$regex = '/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/';
    $rules = [
    'nextcontactSchool' => 'nullable|digits_between:7,10',
    'websiteSchool' => 'nullable|regex:' . $regex,
    ];
```

I did this in a controller once i figured that i can't properly make use of a rule. But the problem here is that, I cant seem to pass the empty data to the database and everytime that i do that, i get a error message.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: You don't need to manually check for `null`s; you should be able to do `$this->validate($request, ['websiteSchool' => 'nullable|url', 'nextcontactSchool' => 'nullable|digits_between:7,10']);`. If the value is `null`, none of the subsequent validation is executed. Beyond that, when you say *"i get a error message."*, what, **specifically**, is the error?

Comment: @TimLewis this was the first thing i did, but upon doing this, it still executes the regex and digits between queries.

$rules = [
'nextcontactSchool' => 'nullable|digits_between:7,10',
'websiteSchool' => 'nullable|regex:' . $regex,
]

return $rules;

Comment: Oh really? I wonder if that's a Laravel 5 thing  That version is pretty old, so I can't verify. But, if that is the case, your code _should_ work ok as written. Once again though, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @TimLewis it's really not much of an error but the system not letting me go through with the null/empty value.

Comment: Hmm, you'll have to include the rest of the relevant code if there isn't a specific error message. I'm not 100% sure A) what you're trying to do and B) why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: $regex = '/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/';
    $rules = [
    'nextcontactSchool' => 'nullable|digits_between:7,10',
    'websiteSchool' => 'nullable|regex:' . $regex,
    ];

So, here i don't want to validate a field with a null value, but want to validate a field if the value exists.

The problem : even if the value is null, the validation is taking place.

I'm sry if i couldnt make it clearer.

Comment: No no, I get that, I'm not saying to use my suggested code; use your existing code, but add the `regex` rule to your 1st validation block. Also, don't put updates in the comments, use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72292045/edit) link below your original question.

Comment: hmm...doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: I already said stop trying to use `'nullable|digits_between:7,10'` and `'nullable:regex:  '. $regex`; **use your original code** and add the Regex rule to that: `if ($request->get('websiteSchool') !== 'null' || $request->get('nextcontactSchool') !== 'null') { $this->validate($request, ['websiteSchool' => 'url', 'nextcontactSchool' => 'digits_between:7,10|regex: ' . $regex]); ... `

Comment: You've already established that combining the `nullable` rule with the other validations doesn't work, so use your original code and try to make that work.

Comment: What the error are you getting if you use nullable|url as a validation rule for websiteSchool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nullable and it will pass if websiteSchool and nextcontactSchool are not present

```
$request->validate([
    'websiteSchool' => ['nullable', 'url'],
    'nextcontactSchool' => ['nullable', 'digits_between:7,10']
]);
```

If this is not what you need, consider the following validation methods:

- [required_if](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-if)
- [present](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-present)

Comment: i tired doing this as well... even tried adding 'sometimes' and 'nullable' together as some of the others threads suggested. just aint seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

so, i came to know the answer behind it. when using nullable it sends a null value for sure but it send's the nullable value in terms of a string. so rather than comparing it to null, we would be comparing it to 'null'.

e.g:

```
if($variable!='null'){
//do something
}
```